# "WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong" WooCommerce error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, error-handling, orders

My function causes error «WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, wc_doing_it_wrong». I've learned about same issues but still can't find where in my function wrong calls are, please help.

Woocommerce 4.3.

Here's the function:

```
add_action( 'init', 'loyal_customer_auto_coupon', 10, 1);

function loyal_customer_auto_coupon(){
    
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        
        $customer = get_current_user_id();
        $acf_user = 'user_' . $customer;
        $loyal = get_field('loyal_customer_coupon', $acf_user); 

        if ($loyal == '') {
            $all_orders = wc_get_customer_order_count( $customer );

            if ( $all_orders > 4 ) {
                $args = array(
                    'customer_id' => $customer
                );
                $orders = wc_get_orders($args);

                $completed_order_count = 0;
                foreach ($orders as $order) {
                    if ( $order->status == 'completed' ) {
                        if ( $order->total > 14.99 ) {
                            $completed_order_count++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since WooCommerce 3 Object properties can't be accessed directly, instead you will use `WC_Order` methods. So in your code, replace

- `$order->status` by  `$order->get_status()`
- `$order->total` by `$order->get_total()`

It should solve your issue.